# NameError in Devise::Registrations - Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes, cancan

I have an application that breaks down different users into categories , i run into Devise error when i choose the third category

Relevant code

#routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do

    get "users/select_user_type" => "devise/registrations#select_user_type"
    get "users/create_creative_user", :to => "devise/registrations#create_creative_user", :as => "create_creative_user"
end
resources :users
```

This is the error i am facing -

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::CreativeRequest

  <%= form_for(CreativeRequest.new,url: {action: "create"},:html=>{:method=>:post,:id=>"create_creative_user"}) do|f| %>
```

Read around a bit and found sometimes cancan causes error with devise , please guide if it's the same case . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CreativeRequest instance` in `form_for` then `CreativeRequest` should be a `model`. Make sure you have a class CreativeRequest in app/models/creative_request.rb.

Comment: Yes , i did have it . Had to change {action: "create"} to  { :action => :create} , dat did it for me . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thats strange as your original code works perfectly fine using  `{action: "create"} `.

Comment: Even i was out of ideas , then i found this suggestion at a forum